# Try set event 'click' on 'pjax:popstate' - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

Small example of Pjax: http://indapublic.ru/pjax/

function **handler** set event click on "Test Link" and output "handler" in Javascript console.

```
function handler() {
    console.log('handler');
    // console.log($('#testLink'));

    $('#testLink').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
    })
}
```

function **handler** execute on **pjax:success pjax:popstate** events.

```
$(document).on('pjax:success pjax:popstate', function() {
    handler();
});
```

Try to click "Test link" after load directly or by Pjax. It will output "click" on Javascript console. But if you go back with "Back" button - function **handler** will be execute, but click on "Test Link" is not working.

Why?

Comment: Instead of outputing 'handler', can you try to output something related to the '#textink' item (like a `console.log($('#testLink')`) and see if it is found when you attach the event.

Comment: @JScoobyCed I update my example. It outputs: [a#testLink, context: document, selector: "#testLink", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…] after load and after popstate

Answer (score 1):

Try to use event delegation, keep this out of the handler method

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#testLink', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('click');
    })
});
```